# Basic Calculator program not working in Python idle

Tags: python

```
loop = 1

choice = 0 #holds the user choice for menu

while (loop == 1):
    print ("Welcome to calci.py")
    print ("your options are:")
    print (" ")
    print ("1. Addition")
    print ("2. Subtraction")
    print ("3. Multiplication")
    print ("4. Division")
    print ("5. Quit calculator.py")
    print (" ")

    choice = input("Choose your option: ")
    if (choice == 1):
        add1 = input("Add this: ")
        add2 = input("to this: ")
        print (add1, "+", add2, "=", add1 + add2)
    elif (choice == 2):
        sub2 = input("Subtract this: ")
        sub1 = input("from this: ")
        print (sub1, "-", sub2, "=", sub1 - sub2)
    elif (choice == 3):
        mul1 = input("Multiply this: ")
        mul2 = input("with this: ")
        print (mul1, "*", mul2, "=", mul1 * mul2)
    elif (choice == 4):
        div1 = input("Divide this: ")
        div2 = input("by this: ")
        print (div1, "/", div2, "=", div1 / div2)
    elif (choice == 5):
        loop = 0

print ("Thankyou for using calci.py!")
```

I am new to the python world, I have written and compiled the calculator code, but its not working,Need help!!

Comment: "Not working" isn't a specific problem. Any errors? Is an logic error? Why so you think that? What values are you passing in? What do you get back? What did you expect? How have you tried to fix this so far?

Comment: It's working for me. Please state the exact error/issue.

Comment: Is this Python 3 or 2? If this is Python 2, I see you're using integer division...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
choice = input("Choose your option: ")
if (choice == 1):
```

here input will return string output. So in your if condition you will need to do like:

```
choice = input("Choose your option: ")
if (choice == '1'):
```

Then it will work. But remember it's will concat two string in above example. So may be you will need to convert that string to integer and then perform your arithmetic.

So you could use like

```
intchoice = int(choice)
if (intchoice  == 1):
```

similarly you need to follow for your add1/add2 and other input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to run your code in Terminal, and it infinitely loops as given.
You initially set choice to zero, but your code does not handle zero, so it doesn't know what to do so it just loops.
Try adding an else block and the end of your elif statements to catch anything that elif doesn't account for.
EX:

```
else:
   print("Error")
   loop=0
```

I see your using a while loop to try and make the program run continually until the user quits.
try using input() or raw_input() to get user choices for the operation. Other then that great job!